# parsing/breaking up DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I need to break up date time, currently when I use:

```
Write(DateTime.Now);
```

it displays: 5/17/2011 03:30:00 PM

What I need it to look like is: 5/17/2011, 03:30:00 PM

I basically need a comma between the date & time.

My thinking was to parse them and write them separately, but I have been unsuccessful in my attempts.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Why not simply compose the string by property? I.E, `myString += myDate.Month + "/" + ...` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.ToString()` method which takes in a format.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Here is a nice little [reference guide](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) to string formatting

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the [`ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) and [`ToShortTimeString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx) methods. You should be able to accomplish what you need in a variety of ways.

```
Write(string.Format("{0}, {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
Write(string.Format("{0}, {1}", dateTime.ToShortDateString(), dateTime.ToLongTimeString()));
```